# Is there any advantage to manually deleting temp folders vs using the Windows Disk Cleanup tool?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, temporary-files, disk-cleanup

I work at an IT call center, and we have a guide that directs us to empty out the following folders for hard drive cleanup:

- C:\Users\ *user* \App Data\local\Temp
- C:\Temp
- C:\Windows\Temp

and then run disk cleanup tool.

Is there any point to this or is it redundant?
I originally wanted to make a script that would empty out these file paths for me, but now i fail to see how that would be any different from running Disk cleanup, which is supposed to delete temp files. I'd just be reinventing the wheel.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as we know, `C:\Temp\` is not a standard temporary folder, although it is probably quite wide-spread.

Most likely, your management team wants to ensure that you really clean out those folders, manually or automatically. *Windows Disk Cleanup* most probably performs actions other than those three, but it might not be customized to the extent desired by your management team.

We are still using "*Symantec*"'s "*Norton Utilities [2,0]16*" Software Optimizer, which *can* be customized toward the user's delight.